# Does the Grothendieck construction satisfy Fubini's thorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, grothendieck-construction

Suppose we are given a functor

$F:(A\times B)^{\operatorname{op}}\to \operatorname{Set}$.

It's well-known that the Grothendieck construction in this case evaluates as

$\int_{A\times B}F = (A\times B)/F$.

We could also apply this construction pointwise to obtain a functor

$\int_A F:B^{op}\to \operatorname{Cat}$

sending $b\mapsto A/F(b)$

and similarly

$\int_B F:A^{op}\to \operatorname{Cat}$

We can apply the Grothendieck construction again to each of these functors to obtain categories

$\int_A\int_B F$

and

$\int_B\int_A F$

Is it the case that $\int_A \int_B F\cong \int_B \int_A F\cong \int_{A\times B} F$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. See section 4.2 of [this](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~harpaz/grothendieck.pdf) paper by Harpaz and Prasma, which also extends the result to the setting of model categories.

Another good source on these topics is [Emily Riehl's book](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/riehl.pdf). The Fubini result is extended to the setting of $n$-categories by [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2ef5/c935ded8444717a43ca9e977fced8cee31ea.pdf) thesis.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch!